# Somar e Subtrair valor da mesma coluna SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes dados:

```
+---------------------------+
| Cod_Art | Armazem | Quant |
+---------------------------+
| 11430001 |   1    |    0  |
| 11430001 |   2    |    3  |
| 11430001 |   3    |    0  |
| 11430001 |   4    |    1  |
+---------------------------+
```

O que preciso é de executar uma `query` com a soma das quantidades de:

`Armazem 1 + Armazem 2 + Armazem 3 - Armazem 4`

Nesse caso o resultado é **2**.

Minha `query` esta assim:

```
select cod_Art, (sum(quant) - (select quant from ccartigos_stock where armazem = 4 and Cod_Art = '11430001'))  as 'quant' 
from ccartigos_stock 
where (armazem = 1 or Armazem = 2 or Armazem = 3) and Cod_Art = '11430001'
group by cod_art 
order by cod_Art
```

No entanto eu não quero limitar a pesquisa apenas ao artigo `11430001` mas sim a todos.

Porem, ao retirar o `where Cod_Art = '11430001'` recebo o seguinte erro:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,> >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Você quer obter apenas uma linha de resultado que some a quantidade total (nesse caso será 4) dos itens que contenham as ids 1, 2, 3 e 4, é isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tenta a query abaixo:**

```
select
    cod_Art,
    sum(case
        when armazem = 4 then -quant
        else quant
    end) as 'quant'
from
    ccartigos_stock
group by
    cod_Art
order by
    cod_Art
```

Answer (score 0):

É mais simples do que você está tentando, usando [IFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574(v=sql.110).aspx) (a partir do SQL Server 2012):

```
select cod_Art, sum(IIF(Armazem = 4, -quant, quant))
from ccartigos_stock
group by cod_art 
order by cod_Art
```

Comment: Resposta atualizada com a sintaxe correta do SQL Server

Answer (score -1):

> O erro é mostrado à você porque quando você retira o filtro
>   (Cod_Art = '11430001') sua consulta retorna mais de um registro, e não
>   é possível realizar a subtração da quantidade. Veja as alterações que
>   fiz que corrigem esse erro e algumas melhorias.

- No sub-select para obter a quantidade total do armazém 4, adicionei um `SUM`, dessa maneira voc~e irá obter apenas o valor total, e poderá realizar a subtração.
- Onde você fazia uma verificação para os demais armazéns, substitui pelo comando `IN`
- Adicionei uma identificação para a tabela utilizando o `AS`, assim fica mais fácil identificar

```sql
SELECT 
    CAS.cod_Art, 
    (SUM(CAS.quant) - 
        SELECT 
            SUM(ARM.quant)
        FROM
            ccartigos_stock AS ARM
        WHERE
            ARM.armazem = 4
        group by ARM.cod_art
    ) AS QTDE
FROM 
    ccartigos_stock AS CAS
WHERE 
    CAS.armazem IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY CAS.cod_art 
ORDER BY CAS.cod_Art
```

Answer (score -1):

Para sua Consulta SQL retornar os valores corretos sem a limitação, você precisa relacionar os 2 Selects, o restante esta ok.

```
SELECT Tabela1.COD_ART
       ,(SUM(Tabela1.QUANT) - (SELECT Tabela2.QUANT
                                 FROM CCARTIGOS_STOCK Tabela2
                                WHERE Tabela2.ARMAZEM = 4
                                  AND Tabela2.Cod_Art = Tabela1.Cod_Art)
                              ) AS 'quant'
  FROM CCARTIGOS_STOCK Tabela1
 WHERE Armazem = 1
    OR Armazem = 2
    OR Armazem = 3
 GROUP BY Tabela1.COD_ART 
 ORDER BY Tabela1.COD_ART
```

Observe que eu dei apelidos para as duas tabelas, assim não da pra misturar os campos!